# Edge-triggering on simple logic

Tags: digital-logic, edge

I'm making a module where a microcontroller can control RAM with only 10 GPIO pins (8 is data D0 through D7 and 2 are control).

One thing I want to do is that the moment a control line is raised, I want a reset to occur on a 74HC164 shift register if the highest data pin (D7) is set.

At first I was thinking using D7 and the control line as nand gate inputs and the reset as the output, but the problem with that is both lines must stay high, but I can't do that with the GPIO line because I use each state for a different purpose For example, low=accept data, high=shift register contents, low-to-high transition=reset, etc.

Is there something like a simple logic gate where an event can happen only when an input is on its rising or falling edge?

At first I was thinking utilizing a monostable multivibrator, but that involves additional timings which could make my project run slower. Are there other alternatives?

Comment: That would be a flip flop with edge clock to reset and set to clear if using those polarities.

Comment: I know I can get an edge-triggered clock input in a flip flop but I was looking to see if I can get one in a logic gate of some sorts. The output would be temporary since I'm trying to create a reset circuit without an additional GPIO pin.

Comment: then use level sensitive S/R FF with 2 gates instead of edge sensitive as you requested https://www.google.ca/search?q=sr+ff+gate&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijkpv3vODPAhUCWCYKHX_SAcgQ_AUICCgB&biw=1376&bih=689#imgrc=z6pWMIy4_13rfM%3A

Answer (score 1):

OnSemi's [AND8408](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/AND8408-D.PDF) describes how you can build an edge detector from a '97 logic gate (Schmitt-trigger (N)AND gate with one inverted input). The pulse width can be adjusted with the R/C values:

[image: edge detector]

Answer (score 0):

You say that you know you can get an edge triggered clock input in a flip flop, but you want one in a logic gate of sorts.  A flip flop is a simple logic gate.  A FF IC is probably cheaper than the monostable multivibrator you mentioned.

Your description of the desired functionality: " For example, low=accept data, high=shift register contents, low-to-high transition=reset, etc."

Perhaps I am misunderstanding, but with this scheme, you would reset every time you shifted the contents.  So anytime you were currently "accepting data" and then decided to "shift register contents" you would immediately clear the original contents of the shift register.

But if you want to avoid a flip flop or latch, you could also create a reset pulse from the rising edge and use this pulse to reset the shift register, similar to this image below:

[image: rising edge pulse generator]

Since the pulse timing is short, the shift register reset needs to be asynchronous.  Additionally, you would need to verify that the pulse width is sufficiently long to reset the shift register (minimum pulse width in the data sheet, or just test and add inverter pairs two at a time until it works; or put cap at each intermediate node to slow down the delay chain and extend the output pulse).

Since you only want to reset if D7 is high, you would also want to maybe gate the input to this circuit with D7 (AND gate with D7 and CLK as inputs, and output going into the circuit shown below).

Additionally, if you need the pulse on both the rising and falling edges of a control line, you can use two pulse detectors (replace the final AND gate in the pulse generator with a NOR gate to convert it into a falling edge pulse generator), followed by an 2 input-OR gate (other input being the rising edge pulse generator) before the reset on the shift register.

Comment: so if I used your circuit in your answer and all chips are 74HC family,  I could take the output of the third inverter and rely on the propagation delay to sufficiently reset a 74HC164 shift register?

Comment: I would recommend checking the datasheets unless you have the IC's handy already, in which case it is easy to build and test.  You could also just simulate it.  Like I said, if the pulse is not wide enough you can add caps at each node in the delay chain to slow it down.